# how to connect my php project in AWS cloud with my on premises Oracle databse?

Tags: php, database, oracle, amazon-web-services, cloud

My php project in aws cloud server but my oracle databse on-premises how to connect? is it possible? Somebody suggested me to do with php rest api method

Comment: Google "aws connect on premise database".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to connect via the internet the connection can be established using public ips. But if you are looking for more secure and scalable solution please read the following.

[Connect Your Data Center to AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/connect-data-center-to-aws/)